# hg log: show when somebody performed a push -f

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible to view in the Mercurial logs all instances where a user performed an `hg push -f` when pushing their changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it is not. Mercurial, out-of-the-box, does not track the history of commands.

If you want to explicitly log such actions, you'll need to use Mercurial's [hooks](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks) to get the information to log. Probably you would be looking at `pre-push` or `post-push`.

Other than that, you could manually infer a few of the instances, such as any multiple heads. New named branches require `-f` to push them, so any named branches may have been done that way. Any multiple heads on the same branch (unnamed branches) that have not been merged were obviously forced pushes. If they have been merged, you'll never know whether the push already had the merge or whether it was forced and then merged later.